# Why did Jango Fett jump into the arena to engage Master Windu?

Tags: star-wars, character-motivation, attack-of-the-clones

Master Windu was a mighty Jedi Master (even Count Dooku couldn't stand a chance against him), and this fact should be popular among the bad guys, if not across the Galaxy. What made Jango Fett think he could take out Master Windu all by himself? Yes, he was flying, and Windu was on the ground, but this hardly matters in a universe with The Force.

Comment: Yeah that was a bit of a dumb move... Jango had guns and missiles but decides to give up his ranged advantage and jetpack to within about 10ft of the badass-est Jedi in the galaxy... And now he has no head.

Comment: Fett killed many Jedi in the EU, so he would have had good reason to believe he could win. From a purely canonical standpoint, however, it's possible that his (Fett's) earlier confrontation with Obi-Wan made him a bit over-confident

Comment: @Daft He has a head. It just isn't in the same place anymore.

Comment: The whole prequel trilogy was terribly written. Looking for meaningful reasons for stuff like this is futile and an exercise in making up a plausible-sounding reason. The real reason is that the writers and director thought it would look cool and play well with the audience. Fans loved Boba Fett in the old movies, so they built in a new character that plays off that popularity, and of course they have him show down against the strongest jedi around, just like in the old film. It's pure calculated plot-making, there is nothing more significant to it.

Comment: The only good things to come out of the prequels were *Clone Wars* and *The Clone Wars*. Maybe some of the John Williams music too? (Related: The meh Matricies 2 and 3 giving rise to *Animatrix*)

Comment: @Daft blasters are easily deflected by light sabers and missiles are easily redirected with the force.  To take out a properly equipped and trained force user you need to overwhelm them or close to melee.

Comment: @Trisped is there canon for that? Force users have focre speed? Wouldn't that mean closing the distance plays to their advantage there too?

Comment: @bharal Force speed also allows them to react faster, which is how they perform the otherwise impossible task of blocking and reflecting multiple blaster bolts with their light sabers.  For cannon there are a number of games like The Force Unleashed and Jedi Academy as well as scenes in the prequels and cartoons over the last 10 years.

Comment: Because it allowed us to see Jango Fett being decapitated.  :)

Comment: [It wasn't actually Jango Fett, but a decoy](https://www.imfineimfine.com/p/this-place-was-home) (read to the end). #CannotConvinceMeThisIsNotCanon

Comment: @Lexible That's why I love fanfic.

Comment: Because he's a putz

Comment: @Valorum A putz who had a track record of killing lots of Jedi.

Comment: [That something worked in the past isn't an indicator that it's sensible or advisable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6v9g4rakOY)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Fett was hardly alone when he jumped into the arena -- a huge battle was in progress in which all the Jedi were fighting an army of battle droids as well as the animals intended to kill Anakin, Obi-Wan, and Padme.

Windu had just lost his lightsaber to a [reek](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Reek) the moment Fett jumped into the arena, and Fett jumped in to try to grab Windu's lightsaber. **Fett was trying to take advantage of Windu's momentary distraction by the reek and the loss of his lightsaber.** Presumably, Fett would have used his jetpack to retreat back to a safe distance, and Windu wouldn't have his lightsaber to deflect Fett's shots (or anyone else's).

Unfortunately for Jango (and poor Boba), Windu was able to use the Force to grab his lightsaber back just before Fett reached it, and then Fett was immediately trampled by the reek and his jetpack destroyed. Fett can't use the Force, so he couldn't know ahead of time that Windu would beat him to the lightsaber by just a moment and that the reek would turn on him and destroy his jetpack.

Fett fought well against Obi-Wan on Kamino and had defeated other Jedi, so he probably felt he would be able to defeat Windu with the help of the battle droids, animals, and the fact that Windu wouldn't have his lightsaber.

Comment: also do those tiny little blasters really look all that effective at a distance? the longest distance he fired them was right at the start of that fight with Obi-Wan on Kamino

Comment: @IG_42 Yes, they are actually very effective. He took down the reek with **one** shot after it destroyed his jetpack.

Comment: @IG_42 Size matters not. Look at me. Judge me by my size, do you?

Answer (score 8):

The [novelization](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_%28novel%29) addresses that issue. Please note that the most important factor is **#3 combined with #1**:

1. Mace "started it" by holding a lightsaber to Fett's throat (meaning, Fett knew he should attack Mace while he was busy with droids - **and temporarily unarmed, as shown in the next bullet point**), and not wait till he was done and attack Fett one on one.

   > The Count's expression changed, though, just for a moment, as a familiar hum began right behind him. He glanced to his right quickly, to see **a purple lightsaber blade right beside Jango Fett's neck**, then turned slowly to regard the wielder.
2. As such, Fett **already** started fighting Mace...

   > Mace Windu spun about, recognizing that his most dangerous enemies were behind him. **He faced Jango Fett--and found himself looking down the barrel of a stout flamethrower**. A burst of flames reached out for the Jedi Master, igniting his flowing robes.
3. Fett went to the arena to fight Mace Windu - as indicated above - because he needed to do so before Mace was free to attack him again - AND because **Mace was NOT armed at that moment** - disarmed by the reek:

   > The reek followed Mace, and he had to slash wildly to fend it off. **He did manage to drive it back, but was butted and lost his lightsaber in the process**. He came up facing the reek, and figured that he could outmaneuver it to get his weapon back easily enough, but then an armored rocket-man flew down in his path, blaster leveled.
   >
   > ... **Mace reached out with the Force and brought his lightsaber flying to his hand**, moving like lightning to parry Jango's first shot.
4. It clearly shows that Fett was NOT trying to engage Mace short distance, but was trying to widen the gap, the moment Mace recovered his lightsaber:

   > The Jedi was on him immediately, lightsaber weaving through the air. **Jango dodged and lifted into the air with his rockets**, trying to keep one step ahead of that deadly blade and to occasionally fire a bolt at Mace.

Comment: I don't understand point 1. Did Windu give Jango warning and leave him before?

Comment: @SS - He attacked Jango (as his FIRST step on Geonosis), by putting a lightsaber to Jango's neck. That to Jango means he's Windu's priority target

Comment: Which raises another question, why threaten Jango? I know Jedi aren't exactly in the habit of stabbing people in the back, but shouldn't Dooku have been his primary target? And why would Mace expect Dooku to care about the life of a mercenary in his employ?

Comment: @KSmarts - Novelization covers that. Jango was the most dangerous there and thus Windu needed to cover him.

Comment: @DVK Jango was more dangerous than even Dooku?

Comment: @SS-3.1415926535897932384626433 - Mace Windu thinks so

Comment: @DVK Now, you are going in loop...

Comment: I can hardly see how Jango could be more dangerous than Dooku.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a canonical answer (although the novelization might offer some hints as to his thoughts), but it's probably because he's a Mandalorian and Mace Windu is a Jedi. Due to the Mandalorian Wars, there's a lot of bad blood between the two groups. Combine that with a fair degree of arrogance in his combat prowess, and he leapt into the fray.

Quoting from the Wikipedia article, it seems that Jango had a particular reason to hate the Jedi.

> Jango took command of the remaining True Mandalorians, but unknowingly led them into a trap at the Battle of Galidraan, where they were framed for murder, resulting in the complete destruction of the True Mandalorians at the hands of the Jedi. Jango is the only survivor, and before being captured, slays half of the members of the Jedi Council as well as a few Jedi Knights single-handedly.

Comment: I don't know - Fett seems too practical for revenge to be a motivation. In fact, he was working for Dooku despite KNOWING that Dooku led the Jedi in the slaughter at Galidraan. It doesn't make sense that he would kill other Jedi out of a generic hatred, yet serve the one who actually killed his fellow Mandalorians. Rather, I think he realized that Windu was simply the biggest threat at the time.

Comment: @Omegacron
You know, that makes perfect sense. Hmm... I don't know if I really have anything substantive to add here.

Answer (score 4):

The original film script ([as written](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Attack-of-the-Clones.html)) indicates that the fight between Fett and Windu was pretty much continuous. My guess would be that it's only down to an editing decision that it looks like there was a delay in his jumping into the arena after Windu.

> COUNT DOOKU signals. THOUSANDS OF DROIDS start to pour into all parts
> of the arena.
>
> MACE WINDU draws his lightsaber, JANGO FETT draws his guns and fires
> at MACE WINDU, who deflects the shots. **JANGO FETT and MACE WINDU
> jump into the arena, where they fight.** BOBA FETT watches his Dad and
> the Jedi Master fight. The battle begins.
>
> GEONOSIANS fly away everywhere. DROIDS fire at JEDI, who deflect the
> bolts and cult down the DROIDS. The GEONOSIAN TROOPS fire ray guns
> that are more difficult for the JEDI to deflect.

Answer (score 0):

He has killed many Jedi in the past with his bare hands and probably did not know who Windu was.

Answer (score 0):

Jango jumped in the minute mace lost his lightsaber. Dooku probably had some agreement to pay Fett extra for every Jedi he killed, so he figured Mace would be an easy target.